# Line drop in text editing Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android-studio, text, android-edittext, multiline

Any suggestion how to have an `EditText` that receiving user input around 9 letters (or digits) and after finish (e.g: click some button action or lost keyboard focus), it'll update the letters inside that `EditText`. Following are the requirements:

Input: `123456789`

Output:

```
123 
456 
789
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgMeB.jpg)

Comment: Please have some clarity in the question. Your question doesn't have full stops (.) and goes on continuing without sentence breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm if this is what you want to achieve?

> There's `EditText`, you want that `EditText` able to add newline (multiline) for every 3 character (after a simple actions)

If yes, here's an opinionated solutions that might solve the underlying problems:

[image: kotlin playground examples]

The above screenshot is written in [here](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

For the `EditText` part, what we can think of at the moment:

> See Core-KTX extensions from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/widget/package-summary#doaftertextchanged)

```kotlin
// YourActivity.kt
import androidx.core.widget.doAfterTextChanged
import kotlin.text.buildString // this import is optional. to identify its origin

override fun onCreate(...) {
    // assign your `editText` & `textView` variable with usual `findViewById` or using `ViewBinding` if your project already using it

    // Directly listen for user input in EditText
    editText?.doAfterTextChanged { userInput ->
       if (userInput.length == 3) textView?.text = "$userInput\n"
    }

    // Or you can use the below approach:
    textView.text = buildString {
         editText?.toString()?.forEachIndexed { index, letter -> 
                append(c)
                // index start from 0
                // index+1 = 0+1, so we can start from 1-index
                // check for the reminder of index/3 == 0
                // meaning we are appending the `\n` (newline) to the text
                if ((index+1) % 3 == 0) append("\n")
         }
    }
}

// your_activity.xml
<LinearLayout 
   ...
   <EditText ... id="@id/editText" />
   // create below TextView as a result of user inputs
   <TextView ... id="@id/textView" />
/>
```

> A few lines in the above snippet code omitted for readability, and yes there's a few code will compile-error as well, needs to adjust it accordingly

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, but I want it in Java and I want to separate the words, that is, not to move part of the word and keep the second part with the line above
For example
Thanks don't be
Tha
nks

Comment: cmiiw, , did u mean separate the word inside an `EditText` directly? Or did you have any image or example what you wanna to achieve? 

Comment: Dude, I added a picture of you
I have a project to make a pdf file, but when I write continuously, the letters come out of the file frame.

Comment: Paint paint = new Paint();
                            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder((int) 595, 842, 1).create();
                            PdfDocument.Page mypage1 = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
                            Canvas canvas = mypage1.getCanvas();

Comment: Looks like this requires a different question, how about open a new question to provide more detailed information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349468/pdf-file-does-not-stop-and-continues-and-does-not-drop-line

Comment: Yes, I asked this question, please watch it