# PDF file does not stop and continues and does not drop line

Tags: java, android-studio, pdf, android-edittext, itext

I have a problem that the PDF file has no start and stop limits, when I write the line it goes on and no line goes down, how can I do that?
This is a picture of the situation
[image]
This is the code I used

```
 Paint paint = new Paint();
                PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder((int) 585, 842, 1).create();
                PdfDocument.Page mypage1 = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
                Canvas canvas = mypage1.getCanvas();
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755621/how-to-position-and-wrap-long-text/2762518

Comment: No brother, it does not work

Comment: Which event fires the code ?

Comment: I need a code that makes the text sequential in lines

Comment: could you provide a snippet code that assign the text to PDF? I'm curious with the variable `pdfDocument`

Comment: Do you want the complete code?